# How to select all variables declared in XSL?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to loop through all variables declared in my XSL. Is this possible using XPath?
I need the XPaith syntax to be used in an XSL "for each".

Comment: The real question is why do you think you need to do this?  Every variable you want to use must be explicitly declared with a `<xsl:variable>` or `<xsl:param>` so you already know up-front what variables you have available.  If you want some structure you can "loop through" then you probably want one variable whose value is a set of nodes rather than a set of different variables holding one node each.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible - there is no way to access all variables in a single expression, variables can only be referenced individually using their name prefixed with `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps doing

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:variable">...</xsl:for-each>
```

comes close (if you want the top-level variables). But that simply reads in the stylesheet as an XML document and gives you access to the `xsl:variable` elements in the stylesheet code, it does not give you access to any variable values computed at run-time.